# ¿Cómo puedo contrar una columna que esté relacionada con otra columna?

Tags: python, csv

Buenas tardes : Tengo un csv que contiene lista de desaparecidos tiene columnas que cada uno tiene su propiedad (Nombre, aspecto ,etc) hay columnas 2 que me quiero enfocar Genero(sexo): Male y
Female , Cuando_Desaparecio (fechas ej : 20/10/2018, 2/09/2020) el problema es que quiero contar cuantos mujeres desaparecieron en el 2018 ,2019 y 2020 :

```
def MujeresDesaparecidas (Doc):
    Cuando_Desparecio = [s.Cuando_Desparecio[6:10] for s in Doc]
    Genero = (list(s.Genero for s in Doc))
```

([6:10] < es la parte donde esta los años )

```
A = Counter(Cuando_Desparecio)
    return print(A)
salida : 
Counter({'2018': 353, '2019': 325, '2020': 322})
```

no se como iniciar  la condición para relacionar los 2 columnas.

Espero su ayuda .

Comment: Que es s? Un dataframe?

Comment: sip es un excel

Comment: Nos podrías proporcionar el dataframe? Así se podrá hacer pruebas y no solo hablar según lo teórico

Comment: Se puede ser más claro agregando información mínima similar o igual a la estructura de la fuente de datos, y si usas solo diccionario o te permites el uso de librerías como `pandas`. Adicionalmente agrega la salida que esperas para tener como referencia de forma más clara lo que buscas.